# Python ML Linear Regression object not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to make a ML with LinearRegression that tells me the price of the house based on the area.
I've tryed many sugestions but same error keep showing.
When i access the joblib from another file the same error occurs.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import joblib

model = LinearRegression()

df = pd.read_csv('resources\\homeprices.csv', sep=',')

model.fit(df[['area']], df.price)
#ready_model = model.fit(df[['area']], df.price)

joblib.dump(model, 'models\precolinear.joblib')
#joblib.dump(ready_model, 'models\precolinear.joblib')

print(model[[150]])
```

the Main file i use for the ML Call is:

```
import joblib


class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.predictor = joblib.load('./models/precolinear.joblib')

    def predict(self, text):
        cost = self.predictor(text)
        return cost
```

This is the training info: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hmgb.png)

Comment: What are you thinking print(model[[150]]) does?

Comment: could you add the full traceback of the error you're getting?

Comment: It should be self.predictor.predict(text) imo.